# Method signature changes when filtering

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

For some reason, its not accepting my parameters when in filter mode.
What do i need to do?

error:

```
Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Filter.getRange.
CollectCases
```

works:

```
var SS = partner_list.getSheetByName("Ark 1");
 SS.getRange("A2:R");
```

not work:

```
var SS = partner_list.getSheetByName("Ark 1");
 SS.getFilter().getRange("A2:R");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What causes the error is that `SpreadsheetApp.Filter.getRange` doesn't accept any parameters, unlike `SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange`.

It will just return the range where the filter was applied. (There can only be a single filter per sheet)

Here is a sample workaround by using `offset` if you only want to fetch a specific part of the filter range.

#### Workaround:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  // Filter is applied to "A6:A12" with values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
  var range = ss.getFilter().getRange();

  // If you only want a part of the filtered range
  // Then, you need to use offset
  // E.g. You want filtered A10:A12 with values 4, 5, 6
  var rowOffset = 3;
  var colOffset = 0;
  var rows = range.getValues().length - rowOffset;

  // rowOffset = number of rows offset (3 rows below)
  // colOffset = number of columns offset (same column)
  // rows = number of rows to be fetched
  Logger.log(range.offset(rowOffset, colOffset, rows).getValues());
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Resources:

- [getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter#getRange())